# Computing Infinity Harmonic Operator of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider the cone function $ C(x) := a |x-z| + b $ and the paraboloid $ P(x) := -\gamma | x- z|^2 $ for given constants $ a,b $ and $ \gamma  $ where $ a >0 $. I'd like to compute $ \Delta_\infty (C+P) $. At the page 474 of the article http://users.jyu.fi/~peanju/preprints/tour.pdf is stated that \begin{equation}\label{key}
 \Delta_\infty (C+P)(x) = \Delta_\infty G (|x-z|) = G''(|x-Z)G'(|x-z|)^2 = -2\gamma (2 \gamma |x-z| - a)^2.
 \end{equation}
I can see the second inequality. However, I can't see the others. I know that
    $$
 (C+P)_{x_i} (x) = G'(|x-z|)\dfrac{(x_i- z_i)}{|x-z|}
 $$
    \begin{eqnarray*}
  (C+P)_{x_ix_j} (x) &=& G''(|x-z|)^2\dfrac{(x_i- z_i)}{|x-z|} \dfrac{(x_j- z_j)}{|x-z|} \\
  &+& G'(|x-z|)\left [ \dfrac{\delta_{ij}}{|x-z|} - (x_i- z_i)(x_j- z_j)\dfrac{1}{|x-z|^3}\right ]
 \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes. I mean exactly this second inequality.

Comment: I see. I think we were on different pages regarding what $\Delta_\infty G(\lvert x - z \rvert)$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first/second equality, let's just show that $\Delta_\infty(C+P)(x) = G''(\lvert x - z\rvert) G'(\lvert x - z \rvert)^2$. We compute, as you found (up to rearrangement and a typo),

\begin{align*}
(C+P)_{x_i}(x)     &= G'(\lvert x - z \rvert) \frac{x_i - z_i}{\lvert x - z \rvert},
\\
(C+P)_{x_i x_j}(x) &= G''(\lvert x - z \rvert) \frac{(x_i - z_i)(x_j - z_j)}{\lvert x - z \rvert^2} + G'(\lvert x - z \rvert) \left( \frac{\delta_{ij}}{\lvert x - z \rvert}  - \frac{(x_i - z_i)(x_j - z_j)}{\lvert x - z \rvert^3} \right).
\end{align*}

Computing the sum defining $\Delta_\infty$, the key is to recognize that the various sums of terms involving the components of $x-z$ are just powers of $\lvert x - z \rvert$:

\begin{align*}
\Delta_\infty(C+P)(x)
&= \sum_{i,j} (C+P)_{x_i}(x) \, (C+P)_{x_j}(x) \, (C+P)_{x_i x_j}(x)
\\
&= G''(\lvert x - z \rvert) \, G'(\lvert x - z \rvert)^2 \frac{\sum_{i,j} (x_i - z_i)^2 (x_j - z_j)^2}{\lvert x - z \rvert^4}
\\
&\phantom{=} \phantom{X} + G'(\lvert x - z \rvert)^3 \left( \frac{ \sum_{i,j} \delta_{ij} (x_i - z_i)(x_j - z_j)}{\lvert x - z \rvert^3} - \frac{\sum_{i,j} (x_i - z_i)^2 (x_j - z_j)^2}{\lvert x - z \rvert^5} \right)
\\
&= G''(\lvert x - z \rvert) \, G'(\lvert x - z \rvert)^2 \frac{\lvert x - z \rvert^4}{\lvert x - z \rvert^4} + G'(\lvert x - z \rvert)^3 \left( \frac{\lvert x - z \rvert^2}{\lvert x - z \rvert^3} - \frac{\lvert x - z \rvert^4}{\lvert x - z \rvert^5} \right)
\\
&= G''(\lvert x - z \rvert) \, G'(\lvert x - z \rvert)^2.
\end{align*}

As for the third equality, just differentiate $G(s) = as - \gamma s^2 + b$.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, there was a typo in my question.